# How to delete all words that follow a certain string to the end of a line, using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

[image]

How can i remove all words after `<de>` till the end of the last word, not the line itself?

I have used this code, but have a problem selecting the expansion range:

```
With Selection
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    '  Find the entered texts.
    With Selection.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = strTexts
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute
    End With

    Do While .Find.Found = True
      '  Expand the selection to the entire sentence.

      Selection.Expand Unit:=wdLine

        Selection.Delete

      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is very close. What's missing is moving it back by one character (`wdCharacter, -1`).

Note I've also corrected the `Find.Wrap` setting to `wdFindStop`. If you use `wdFindContinue` your code could enter an infinite loop - it could keep starting over at the beginning of the document.

```
Sub FindTheDeleteToEndOfLine()
    Dim searchTerm As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    searchTerm = "<de>"
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    'Basic Find settings
    With Selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    'Execute the Find
    Do
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = searchTerm
            bFound = .Execute
            If bFound Then
                Selection.MoveEnd wdLine, 1
                Selection.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
                Selection.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Loop While bFound
End Sub
```

Comment: Note the photo comes from a table of contents ,it removes the whole table when i use your code. also some part of the document contain <de> then the next line is the rest of the sentence the code only remove <de> and leaves everything after it.

Comment: @AbdoShabana Well, give us that information in your problem description! I answered what you asked. You can't effectively edit a Table of contents - that's a field code. You first need to turn the TOC into plain text if you want to edit it. Or you need to generate the TOC without the text you don't want.

Comment: I thought about marking the first part (i.e. <en>*<de>) then deleting the rest of the sentence or line. after that i can just do a normal replace. but i am unable to delete the rest of the sentence except the marked part.

Answer (score 1):

The code below deletes everything after `Slim Shady` up to the end of the line.
Thus from:

[image]

you get:

[image]

```
Public Sub DeleteAfterEminem()

    Do While True
        Selection.HomeKey wdStory
        With Selection
            .Find.Text = "Slim Shady"
            If .Find.Execute Then
                .MoveEnd wdLine, 1
                .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
                .Delete
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        End With
    Loop

End Sub
```

---

If you want to remove everything from `Slim Shady` to the end of the document this is a working solution:

```
Public Sub DeleteAfterEminem()

    With Selection
        .Find.Text = "Slim Shady"
        If .Find.Execute Then
            .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End
            ' .End = Selection.End
            .Delete
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont want to delete anything after slim shady, i just want to delete every thing till the end of the line . so that 4th sentence will appear. but only the first part of it.